# How to know if the UML class diagram design is good (well-planned) or not in java

Tags: java, object-oriented, uml

I've learned the UML recently and I am trying to build a MonsterDuel system. However, there are a lot of classes in this project, and I am confused about the abstract class and its usage. Now, I have created:

1. Abstract class `Players`, and its inherited class `Player`.
2. Abstract class `Field`, and its subclasses: `Monster`, `Spell`, `Tomb`, `FieldSpell`, and `CardDeck`.
3. The multiple card classes associated with each other. The `Monster`, `SpellCard`, and `TrapCard` form up the entire `PlayerCardSelection`.

To be specific, I will try my best to wrap up the questions.

1. Are there any rules or principles to determine if the UML a good design before coding?
2. I am not sure if the abstract class can inherit another abstract class.
3. If it is bad, how and what can I do to improve?

What I've tried is to separate the entities that I think is independent of the others. For example, I can add players by initializing the instance in the `Player` class, and inherited the attributes from the abstract class `Players`.

For the card section, I did a hierarchy structure to form up a card deck that can be selected and used by a player.

I haven't added all of the `setter` and `getter`, just want it to be as clean as possible. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you lower it down to the use of abstract classes it would be a valid question on SO (where you previously asked but also in a too broad way). You can not ask on opinions. Only on facts.

Comment: right, thank you. I'll specify next time.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any rules or principles to determine if the UML a good design before coding?

Yes. Show it to a fellow programmer and ask if they understand what the UML is even trying to say.

> I am not sure if the abstract class can inherit another abstract class.

Yes. So long as eventually you get to a concrete class. Too much of this will give you the yo-yo problem.

> If it is bad, how and what can I do to improve?

Talk to the fellow programmer about the issue that is making it bad and find a different way to satisfy your requirement.

I can't do any of this with you though because I can't even read this thing. You have too much going on for one page.